# Matlab 2019 gives abnormal errors when launching

Tags: matlab

I have just downloaded Matlab toolbox and I think I did a mistake somewhere but don't know where. I have two versions of Matlab on my machine and I when I launch Matlab 19, the one I want to use, I get this two lines of error:

> Unable to resolve the name slreq.utils.loadLinkSet.
>
> Error in rmiml.getAll

When I run the first section, which is merely

```
clear all; close all; clc;
```

I get this error

> Cannot find builtin function '_LiveEvaluate'

I really don't know what happened and how I could solve it. I have checked the environment variables and they seem okay.

When I run the whole script (without doing by section), I have this error occurring

> Attempt to execute SCRIPT mrdivide as a function:
> C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019b\toolbox\matlab\ops\mrdivide.m
> Error in Sandbox (line 25)
> X=1/2*eye(n);

Comment: “I just downloaded a toolbox” I guess you also installed it? What did that involve? What toolbox is this? Is `rmiml` related to the toolbox? You’re giving us very few details here.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I have updated my question but I don't think the cause really lies in the package itself. I have two versions of Matlab on my machine (2019b and 2022) and my intuition is that the errors come from some environment variable problem but I am not sure at all...

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with having multiple versions of MATLAB on the same system. Whatever you did to install this toolbox could have broken your MATLAB installation. Why don’t you just delete it and reinstall?